# How to differentiate stdout logs?

Tags: docker, stdout, supervisord

We have an application running on docker; currently all logs are getting written to log files. We want to move logs to `stdout`. We have used `/dev/fd/1` to write logs to `stdout` and it is working.

**App A** has below logs:

```
nginx log 
supervisor log
app-supervisor log
```

**nginx config**, this is the change:

```
access_log /dev/fd/1 main;
error_log /dev/fd/1 error;
```

in **supervisor** config, this is the change:

```
stdout_logfile=/dev/fd/1
```

Sample Supervisor:

```
[program:app]
command=/bin/bash -c "exec npm run start-generic"
directory=/app01
stdout_logfile=/dev/fd/1
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=0
stopasgroup=true

[program:nginx]
command=/usr/sbin/nginx -g "daemon off;"
stdout_logfile=/dev/fd/1
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

Now problem is all logs are getting written to `stdout`. I want to differentiate these logs (i.e putting some identifier in front of each lines where they come from).

Something like below:

```
[app] .....app log line1...
[app] .....app log line2...
[nginx] ....nginx log line1...
[app] .....app log line3...
[nginx] ....nginx log line2...
```

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else is looking for the answer -

you can use use supervisor stdout event listener -

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon = true    << make it true 

[program:web]
command = ...
stdout_events_enabled = true.       <<< add these lines in your each program config
stderr_events_enabled = true        <<< add these lines in your each program config

[eventlistener:stdout]
command = supervisor_stdout
buffer_size = 100
events = PROCESS_LOG
result_handler = supervisor_stdout:event_handler
```

This will append the program name in front of each line.  But I saw log duplication when using this.

OR
if you don't want to use event listener and don't want to change your code the you can use tail program to tail logs and use sed to append some text.

Suppose below is your config -

```
[program:app]
command=/bin/bash -c "exec npm run start-generic"
directory=/app01
stdout_logfile=/logs/app.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=50
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=0
stopasgroup=true

[program:nginx]
command=/usr/sbin/nginx -g "daemon off;"
logfile = /logs/nginx.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=50
```

Then add tail job in config to write in stdout and append string before it -

```
[program:nginx-log-access]
command=/bin/bash -c "tail -f /logs/nginx.log | sed 's/^/[nginx-access] /'"
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0

[program:nginx-log-error]
command=/bin/bash -c "tail -f /logs/nginx-error.log | sed 's/^/[nginx-error] /'"
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0

[program:app-log]
command=/bin/bash -c "tail -f /logs/app.log | sed 's/^/[app-access] /'"
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly answering the question but I would suggest using docker-compose. Create all the components of the app as services under docker-compose. Now, when you fire it up using `docker-compose up` you not only get different logs labelled according to service but also the convenience to manage them separately and in a simpler way.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but, we can't use docker compose because all of our applications are running on AWS ECS.

Comment: Still this answer suggests correctly that you shouldn't run all components in a single container in the first place